# jQuery : reserve key this, and ambiguous cases

Tags: jquery

I´m littel confused with `this` reserve key and cases caused errors. Here a sample code where this causes errors.

```
var sample = {
    init: function() {
        this.sampleFunction0();
        this.sampleFunction1();
    },
    sampleFunction0 : function(){
        var something0, something1, something2;
        something0 = this.sampleFunction2(); // works, there is no ambiguity whit 'this'
        jQuery('#list li').click(function(){
            something1 = this.sampleFunction2(); // ambiguity: not works, but sample.sampleFunction2(); works
            something1 = sample.sampleFunction2(); // it´s works
            something2 = $(this).text(); // list item val
            console.log(something0) // something
            console.log(something1); // something : using sample.sampleFunction2();
            console.log(something2); // item val
        });
    },
    sampleFunction1 : function(){
        return 'someting';
    },
    sampleFunction2 : function(){
        return 'something';
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    sample.init();
});
```

I don´t know if is correct to use `sample.sampleFunction2();` instead `this.sampleFunction2();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I think you probably know this, but: Within the event handler, `this` refers to the element on which you hooked the event, which is of course why `this.sampleFunction2()` doesn't work. So `this` will be the `li` element that was clicked — which is frequently quite handy.

In your specific case, using `sample` rather than `this` is fine, because your `sample` object is a one-off, there won't be more than one of it. So yes, just use `sample.sampleFunction2();` instead of `this.sampleFunction2();`.

In cases where there may be more than one (things created via a constructor function, etc.), the typical thing to do in this case (no pun) is to define a local variable in your closure (your function you're passing into `click`) can close over:

```
sampleFunction0 : function(){
    var something0, something1, something2, self = this; // <==== CHANGE
    something0 = this.sampleFunction2(); // works, there is no ambiguity whit 'this'
    jQuery('#list li').click(function(){
        something1 = self.sampleFunction2(); // <==== CHANGE
        something2 = $(this).text(); // list item val
    });
},
```

There are times when it's useful to use jQuery's [`proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy) function, but not in this case, because A) you're *already* defining a closure, and B) you're using `this` for something else. `proxy` is useful when you're trying to bind a function that you've defined elsewhere, and when you need `this` to have a specific value other than the one it would normally have.

More reading:

- *[You must remember `this`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)*
- *[Mythical methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)*
- *[Closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)*

Comment: thanks for answer and references. I´m new in JS and jQuery and It´s great learn day by day.

Comment: @Marcos: No worries, glad to help. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I believe, $.proxy() can help you with this issue:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Comment: `proxy` can help in many cases, but there are two reasons not to use it here: 1) He's *already* defining a closure, so `proxy` just adds further overhead; 2) He's using `this` within the event handler to refer to the element he's hooked `click` on, which you frequently do want to do in event handlers. Using `proxy` would make `this = sample` instead, leaving you with no ready way to access the actual element that was clicked. (You could use `$(event.target).closest("#list li")`, but that's a lot more work.)

Answer (score 0):

When you are insied a jQuery function `this` can have different meanings. In this case:

```
 jQuery('#list li').click(function(){
```

this refers to the clicked element and so

```
 this.sampleFunction2();
```

tries to access a method on the clicked element.You should copy "this"

```
 var that = this;
 jQuery('#list li').click(function(){
        something1 = that.sampleFunction2(); /
        something2 = $(this).text(); // list item val
        console.log(something0) // something
        console.log(something1); // something : using sample.sampleFunction2();
        console.log(something2); // item val
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

the context within `click()` is the clicked element, so this refers to the element on wich received the click event. You can use `sample.sampleFunction2()`